# Laravel Auth: How to get user model from Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using multiauth feature using `ollieread/multiauth` package. Which return me object of class `Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser`. With this I can access the class property using `Auth::user()->get()->{class_property}`

But this works fine for class properties only and not for member functions. I have mentioned relationship in the `User` model but I am not able to access it via `Auth::user()->get()->profile()`

the `profile` is mentioned inside `User` model which is `hasOne()` relation with `user_profile` table.

Any idea how to get `User` model from `GenericUser` class?

Comment: Try `Auth::user()->profile`

Comment: @MattBurrow throws error, trying to access undefined property

Comment: Ok then. Having a look at the docs on the package, try this; `Auth::user()->get()->profile` without the ().